# how to write 2 D list contents to file in specific format?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a 2D List whose contents are:

```
[['LIB00001', 'Case Beast', 2], ['LIB00002', 'Dressed gold', '4'], ['LIB00003', 'City terror', '5'], ['LIB00004', 'The Fame', '6'], ['LIB00005', 'Sign Fire', '10']]
```

I want to write these to a text file with the below format:

```
LIB00001_Case Beast_3
LIB00002_Dressed gold_4
LIB00003_City terror_5
LIB00004_The Fame_6
LIB00005_Sign Fire_10
```

Could someone help me please?

Comment: in `list` there is `...'Case Beast', 2...`, but in expecting output `Beast_3`, is this a typo?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your list is named `l`, and that the integer `2` in the first sub-list is a typo that should really be a string `'2'` like the rest of the sub-lists, (or `'3'`, from your expected output), the following code will write the expected output to `filename`:

```
with open('filename', 'w') as f:
    f.write('\n'.join(map('_'.join, l)))
```

Or if some of the numbers in the sub-lists really are integers, you can cast them to strings first:

```
with open('filename', 'w') as f:
    f.write('\n'.join(map('_'.join, [[str(i) for i in s]for s in l])))
```

Comment: getting bellow error
   `code` f.write('\n'.join(map('_'.join, self.availablebooks)))
TypeError: sequence item 2: expected str instance, int found `code`

Comment: That's why I said your `2` might be a typo. Are you sure it isn't really `'2'`, like the numbers in the rest of the sub-lists?

Comment: actually - I am modifying it from '3' to '2' to update Qty
`code`r[2]=int(r[2])-1`code`. Should I type cast it back to String before I write it to file?

Comment: Yes, your numbers should be strings, to be consistent with the data type of the rest of the items.

Comment: Thank you.... when i try this- i am getting an error 
`code`r[2]=str(r[2])
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
`code`

Comment: You must have accidentally assigned a list to `str` as a variable, shadowing the built-in function `str`. Please double-check where `str` is referenced and see if it's getting overridden in any way.

Comment: i am doing that on purpose. my code searches for the quantity - which is 3 in this case - subtracts it by 1. to do this I am type casting the string to int. this is why the number is changed to 2. Is there any way to write the list as it is back to file? or convert 2 to '2'
`code`for r in self.availablebooks:
            for c in r:
                if c == self.s:
                    if(int(r[2])>0):
                        print("Book is Issued")
                        r[2]=int(r[2])-1
++> This is where '3' is changed to 2
                        print(self.availablebooks)
`code`

Comment: I just updated my answer with a solution that converts the items in your sub-lists to strings first. Give it a try then.

Comment: No Luck
f.write('\n'.join(map('_'.join, [[str(i) for i in s]for s in self.availablebooks])))
  
    f.write('\n'.join(map('_'.join, [[str(i) for i in s]for s in self.availablebooks])))
  File "/temp/subract_file_qty.py", line 33, in <listcomp>
    f.write('\n'.join(map('_'.join, [[str(i) for i in s]for s in self.availablebooks])))
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Comment: Well again your reference to `str` must've been accidentally overridden somewhere else. You need to post your actual code if you want help here then.

Comment: There it is. You have a `str=[]` that overrides the built-in function `str`. Remove it and the code will work.